# Nginx arg check and rewrite

Tags: php, nginx, arguments, url-rewriting

Could someone help with this situation.

I have

```
location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?sef_rewrite=1;
}
```

but i need to check argument "sl" and "currency" on every url so that

```
http://myurl/page?sl=EN
```

get rewrited to

```
http://myurl/page?sl=EN&currency=EUR
```

also if url is

```
http://myurl/page?sl=BG
```

get rewrited to

```
http://myurl/page?sl=EN&currency=BGN
```

Will this do anything to my pagerank?

Thanks

Comment: You mean PageRank or SEO ?

Comment: Yes, i mean will this rewrite affect PageRank (SEO)

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as i know about SEO, you should create 301 redirects, those would force the google bot to update his old links to your new links, as long as the old links don't do a 404 it's ok

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 diff questions. The 301 is needed for SEO as Mohammad has written.

The rewrite you need is something like:

```
if ($query_string ~* "sl=EN") {
  try_files $request_uri&currency=EN $uri/ /index.php?sef_rewrite=1;
} else {
   try_files $request_uri&currency=EN $uri/ /index.php?sef_rewrite=1;
}
```